# I want to change the HTML from 'OFF' to 'ON' with an onclick event much like a toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to change the HTML from 'OFF' to 'ON.' I can do this by using some jQuery and .html like so:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="sample" onclick="run();"><p>OFF</p></div>
```

**Jquery:**

```
function run(){
  $('.sample p').html("ON");
}
```

However when I do this, I also want to change it back to 'OFF' on another onclick event.
I have tried.. if/else statements, varibles, and switch statements. Nothing seems to work, is there another prefered method to toggle the html?

Using my Google search powers has resulted in no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

HTML:

```
<div class="sample"><p>OFF</p></div>
```

JS:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('.sample p').on('click', function() {
        $(this).html($(this).html() == 'ON' ? 'OFF' : 'ON');
    });
});
```

With jQuery on board there is no need to add an onclick attribute to the HTML tag.

Comment: This works the best, and is more of what I am looking for. Thanks for the reply. I'm pretty new to Jquery and JavaScript, I guess there really isn't a need for the onclick event. Thanks for the insight.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting up a single click handler that inspects the value inside the DIV, and then based on that value, changes it to On or Off.

```
<div class="sample"><p>OFF</p></div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() { 
          run();
    });

    function run(){
      $('.sample').click(function() {
        if ($('.sample p').html() == "on")) {
              // Set to On
        } else {
             // Set to off
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest moving away from the in-line event handling:

```
$('.sample p').click(function(){
    $(this).text(function(i, t){
        return t === 'OFF' ? 'ON' : 'OFF';
    });
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/yc6Un/).

If you want to use the named function, however:

```
function run(){
    $('.sample p').text(function(i,t){
        return t === 'OFF' ? 'ON' : 'OFF';
    });
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/yc6Un/1/).

To extend this function, though, to make it usable with other elements:

```
<div class="sample" onclick="run(this);"><p>OFF</p></div>
```

And jQuery:

```
function run(el){
    var self = el.nodeType === 1 ? $(el) : el;
    self.find('p').text(function(i,t){
        return t === 'OFF' ? 'ON' : 'OFF';
    });
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/yc6Un/2/).

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```
var p = $('.sample p');
p.html( p.html()=="ON" ? "OFF" : "ON" );
```

Answer (score 1):

Move the inline function handler and bind your event in a script file or a script tag.

```
$('.sample').on('click' , function() {
    var $p = $('p', this);

    $p.text() === 'OFF' ? $p.text('ON') : $p.text('OFF');
});
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/yEjzw/)**

Answer (score 0):

Here, let me [write your code for you](http://jsbin.com/uluriz/3/edit):

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("div.sample").click(function() {
        if ($("p", $(this)).html() == "ON") {
            $("p", $(this)).html("OFF");
        } else {
            $("p", $(this)).html("ON");
        }
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="sample">
    <p>ON</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea:

http://jsfiddle.net/Mr2Mk/3/

**HTML**

```
<input class="toggle" type="checkbox"/>
```

**CSS**

```
input.toggle:after {
    content: "OFF";
    margin-left: 1.5em;
}

input.toggle:checked:after {
    content: "ON";
}
```

With more sugar you can turn it into this:

http://dropthebit.com/15/iphone-like-ios5-toggle-buttons/